# xpath btc history into spreadheet

Tags: json, xpath

i'm trying to import the btc price history into a spreadsheet column.
this is the link with the data

```
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=10
```

if i type into one cell:

```
=IMPORTJSON(https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=10, "prices" )
```

it gives me a column with a sequence of numbers from 0 to 239.
what is the correct xpath to get the btc prices?

Comment: share your json script

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
=ImportJson("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=10","/prices")
```